# Build TL-MR3020 emulator

Tags: build, emulation, offline

I have downloaded a TL-MR3020 V1 emulator and I want to build that to use it off-line but I can't.

Could you help with how I can do that?

I have tried to run build_mr3020v1_en.sh in build directory but it wasn't successful.

Comment: What wasn't successful about it? Were there error message? What did you try that caused the errors?

Answer (score 0):

excuse me for delay in answer your question
i read that it has been executed on ubuntu 14.04 successfully so i download it and extract that on ubuntu 14.04 and ran shell file in directory build
but i don't know how should i do to use this or how to run it and utilize this.